# How to Pass Null value to SSRS Report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report and a desktop VB.NET application. In the application the user types in the reports parameters on the application screen then the user clicks a button and I pass this string to view the report:

```
sReportString = "http://eshmreports.as.northgrum.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/CTSReports/DailyUsageReport&rs:Command=Render&StartDate=" + Trim(rptdtpDailyUsageStartDate.Text) + "&EndDate=" + Trim(rptdtpDailyUsageEndDate.Text) + "&Location=" + Trim(txtrptDailyUsageLocation.Text) + "&ChemMat=" + Trim(txtrptDailyUsageChemMat.Text) + "&Source=" + Trim(ddlrptDailyUsageSource.Text) + "&UseCode=" + Trim(ddlrptDailyUsageUseCode.Text) + "&Login=" + Trim(txtrptDailyUsageWho.Text) + "&CTSName=" + Trim(txtrptDailyUsageName.Text)
```

For the Source field I need to pass a Null value if the user leaves the field blank in the desktop application. So that when the report opens, in the Source field on the report is the (NULL) value so the report will run with a Null value for the Source field in the Query.

I have the report set up so that when I run it in Report Builder the (NULL) value shows in the Source field but when I send a blank value from the application I get the  in the Source field.

Comment: iif(isnothing(Parameters!example.Value),nothing,Parameters!example.Value)

Answer (score 0):

For the NULL value you need to pass it as

**Prameter Name:isnull=true**

For example : **CTSName:isnull=true**